# What is the best and fastest way to test whether 2 results are equal?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find whether two solutions are exactly the same in the quickest time possible.

For example:

$$\begin{aligned}
&S_1: \frac{5 \cos ^5(x)}{27 (x+6)^4}\\
&S_2: x
\end{aligned}$$
It is clear that $S_1\neq S_2$, however, I want to generalize this result for any random function $S_1,\, S_2$, without specifically knowing what they are (ex: say the user inputs them). 
`Solve`, `NSolve`, `Reduce` are not able to find a solution for $S_1-S_2=0$, so I tried with `FindRoot`. Now, the problem with `FindRoot`, is that you need an initial value to begin your search with. In the above case, you cannot begin with $-6$ because $S_1$ is undefined at such value. Since my goal is to generalize this to any function, I thought of generating a random number and checking if it is defined in the domain:

```
Catch[If[RI = RandomReal[{-10000, 10000}]; (FunctionDomain[S1 - S2, x] /. x -> RI) == 
True,Throw[RI],Null]] 
(*I would need to add a while loop in order to check again if random 
number is not in domain, but I don't know how to - I though of While
but I can't implement it*)
```

and then (assuming I found a way to add the while loop):

```
If[Length[FindRoot[S1-S2==0,{x,(*Implementation of While Loop with previous code*)}]]!=0,
MessageDialog["You are wrong"], MessageDialog["You are correct"]];
```

However, this gives errors with precision (etc.) as functions become  more complex. So I tried with `FullSimplify`:

```
If[(FullSimplify[S1 - S1] == 0), MessageDialog["You are correct"], 
MessageDialog["You are wrong"]];
```

Which is not the fastes way, and works for $S_1=S_2$ but does **not** display any message when they are not equal.

Which then leads to my last try:

```
If[PossibleZeroQ[S1 - S2], MessageDialog["You are correct"], 
MessageDialog["You are wrong"]];
```

which works and is pretty fast. However, in the documentation center, it states that *`PossibleZeroQ` gives `True` if basic symbolic and numerical methods suggest that `expr` has value zero, and gives `False` otherwise*. So I would not know if this works with more complicated expressions that are equal for many values of x.

Which finally leads to my question: How can I check if two solutions are exactly the same in the fastest time (and less CPU consumption) possible?

---

### **Addendum:**

Another way I thought of would be through the mean squared convergence, so by computing

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(S_1-S_2\right)^2\,dx$$

which might be fast if `NIntegrate` is used, but I am not sure.

I just tried and I get the error

> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand  has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,-4.64782*10^14}}.

which I guess means that it has failed to converge. However, it does not display any `MessageDialog`.

Comment: Would something like "comparing $f(x_i)$ for $n$ random $x_i$" suit you? Also, two unequal functions could give the same result up to the numerical precision. How do you plan to deal with that?

Comment: Note the following line in the documentation of `PossibleZeroQ`: "The general problem of determining whether an expression has value zero is undecidable; `PossibleZeroQ` provides a quick but not always accurate test." Given the fact that you want a fast test, `PossibleZeroQ` is probably going to be your best bet. Otherwise I suggest the `NIntegrate` method on a finite testing domain (instead of the whole real line).